# Hide MSAL Continue Popup from iOS MASL login

Tags: swift, azure-ad-msal

We have implemented MSAL library in iOS Swift  App ( pod version  MSAL 1.1.20).

We are facing issues with the login flow, we are getting extra alert after entering login credentials .
Our configured App name is exposed .

> Screenshots attached below ]

[image]

[Implementation Details here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/hide-msal-continue-popup-from-ios-masl-login/114b1cbb-9740-4afb-a79d-7790b21cd8e1)

**Is there any way to hide this page , and directly get the Token ?**

Comment: @dhirue have you solved it?

Comment: using MSAL against Azure AD, using an embedded WebView prevents the prompt from displaying.
.WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)